# Convert byte-array to a bit byte-array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, byte

Hello stackoverflow community,

I need to convert a byte array to a binary byte-array (yes, binary bytes). See this example:

```
byte[] source = new byte[] {0x0A, 0x00};
//shall be converted to this:
byte[] target = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

//this would be ok as well:
also[0] = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x10};
also[1] = new byte[] {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

At the moment I'm solving this by using Integer.toBinaryString to get the binary string and hexStringToByteArray to convert the binary string to a byte array:

```
for(int o = 0; o < cPage.getCpData().length; o+=cPage.getWidth()) {
    String fBinString = "";
    for(int u = 0; u < cPage.getWidth(); u++) {
        byte[] value =  new byte[1];
        raBa.read(value);
        Byte part = new BigInteger(value).byteValue();
        String binString = Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & part);
        fBinString+=("00000000" + binString).substring(binString.length());
    }
    cPage.addBinaryString(fBinString);
    //binaryCodepage.add(fBinString);
    testwidth = fBinString.length();
    //System.out.println(fBinString);
}
//other class:
public byte[][] getBinaryAsByteArray() {
    Object[] binary =  getBinaryStrings().toArray();
    byte[][] binAsHex = new byte[binary.length][getWidth()*8];
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        binAsHex[i] = ByteUtil.hexStringToByteArray(((String) binary[i]));
    }
    return binAsHex;
}
```

This works fine for small source byte-arrays but takes ages for large byte-arrays. Thats probably caused by the conversion to binary String and back.
Any ideas how to improve this by not converting the source to a String?

Comment: On what basis should 0x0A00 become 0X00001010000000? What does 'binary byte-array' mean? What is a 'bit byte-array'?

Comment: @EJP `0x0A` == `00 00 10 10` in binary.

Comment: So basically, OP, you are spreading the 8 bits from one original byte into a bitfield of length 32, such that each 4th bit is used.

Comment: I would suggest you don't confuse the readers by calling this process "expansion to binary". You are starting from binary form and expanding into another (and quite atypical) binary form.

Comment: I need to expand every byte to 8 bit binary. And the result (binary) is a representation of a new byte array. 2 bits of the binary = 1 new byte
00 = 0x00
10 = 0x10

Comment: That is pretty bizarre code.  Why do you need BigInteger and Integer if the largest value you deal with is byte?  Learn about `&` and `|` and `<<` and `>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's the motivation to this strange conversion, but you could do something similar to the implementation of `Integer.toBinaryString` :

```
private static byte[] toFourBytes(byte i) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4];
    int bytePos = 4;
    do {
        buf[--bytePos] = i & 0x3;
        i >>>= 2;
    } while (i != 0);
    return buf;
 }
```

This should convert (I haven't tested it) each `byte` to a 4 `byte` array, in which each `byte` contains 2 bits of the original `byte`.

EDIT:

I may have missed the exact requirement. If the two bits extracted from the input byte should be in positions 0 and 4 of the output byte, the code would change to :

```
private static byte[] toFourBytes(byte i) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4];
    int bytePos = 4;
    do {
        byte temp = i & 0x1;
        i >>>= 1;
        buf[--bytePos] = ((i & 0x1) << 4) | temp;
        i >>>= 1;
    } while (i != 0);
    return buf;
 }
```

Comment: It's not just that each output byte contains 2 bits. Those bits should be in position 4 and 0 (hex 00, 01, 10, 11; decimal 0, 1, 16, 17).

Comment: @immibis I missed that part of the requirement. Edited the answer to account for that.

Comment: I see. This solution looks good and should work. Will try later.

In case you are curious why I need this: It's needed to decompress data stored in an embedded os firmware.